# SimplePing (macOS) used in a background thread does not work. What are the alternatives?

Tags: swift, macos, grand-central-dispatch, ping

I'm using [Simple Ping](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SimplePing/Listings/SimplePing_m.html) API to ping a bunch of Hosts. 
My class 'PingLatencyCalculator' is a simple wrapper to SimplePing, which calculates the latency and also timesout after 1 second for each request.

```
 let domains = ["www.amazon.com", "www.microsoft.com", "www.yahoo.com", "www.violanation.com", "www.stackoverflow.com", "www.docs.google.com", "www.microsoft.com", "www.google.com", "www.espn.in", "www.dsDSadasdsad.com"]

    let latencyCalculator = PingLatencyCalculator()
    for domain in domains {
        latencyCalculator.pingHost(hostname: domain) { (latency) in
            if let unwrappedlatency = latency {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("\(domain) - Your latency is \(String(describing: unwrappedlatency)))")
                }
            } else {
                    print("\(domain) could not be reached...")
            }
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine. The only issue is that Apple's SimplePing API is build on C libraries and it seems their callbacks won’t work with GCD, thus this has to run in main thread.

Do you think its not a good idea to run this on the main thread?
If i run this on background thread, the callbacks are not called.

So what are my other options to ping hosts concurrently in the background?
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a fix or an alternative library?

Comment: @pnizzle Unfortunately i could not find any.  Since we only had 5-10 API's, we ran it on main thread.  Sorry.